# SQL order by sequence of IN values in query

Tags: mysql

For example I have this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value6,value4,value11,value19)
```

Is there a way to order the result in that exact sequence in the query? The code above returns the default ordering of table_name, completely disregarding the sequence of `IN` values. I know I can do additional coding in PHP to properly order them according to the IN values but that would create a significant overhead.

Answer (score 25):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table_name 
WHERE column_name IN (value6,value4,value11,value19) 
ORDER BY FIELD(column_name,value6,value4,value11,value19)
```

Explanation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field

> - FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)
>
> Returns the index (position) of str in
>   the str1, str2, str3, ... list.
>   Returns 0 if str is not found.

Answer (score 0):

For a DB agnostic answer, look here:
[Order resultset based on WHERE IN clause data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245936/order-resultset-based-on-where-in-clause-data)
However, I would love to have an array construct that is DB agnostic.