# I have a sql query where I have use a list of id inside IN and I want my result sorted as per my list

Tags: php, mysql

My query is

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_patient_bill`
WHERE `bill_code` !=''
AND `is_billed` = 'Y'
AND `charged` = 'N'
AND `id` IN (97,419,631,632,633,422,635,421,35,799,60,423)
```

And I want the record array will be sort according to my list i.e. ID

> '97,419,631,632,633,422,635,421,35,799,60,423'

. I am using php. Please suggest me the optimize way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_patient_bill`
WHERE `bill_code` !=''
AND `is_billed` = 'Y'
AND `charged` = 'N'
AND `id` IN (97,419,631,632,633,422,635,421,35,799,60,423)
ORDER BY FIELD(`id`,97,419,631,632,633,422,635,421,35,799,60,423)
```

Reference: [SQL order by sequence of IN values in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979424/sql-order-by-sequence-of-in-values-in-query)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list of IDs is in an array

1. Run the query
2. Loop through the results, storing each row of results in an associative array keyed on the ID  `$data["{$row['id']}"] = $row;`
3. Loop through your list of IDs, and use the ID to key into the associative array to get the data.  This will be in the order of the IDs you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add an "ORDER BY ID" statement at the end of the query.

Comment: No. It is not belong to the order of column. I should be as per the list I am using inside IN. Need to do by some other technique using php.

Comment: Ok, then I can't help, PHP is not in my domain.